# Having two images linked to one sub panel

Tags: java, swing

I've created a sub panel that I want two images to be linked to. The way that the images would be selected would be from a drop down menu. The way that I've created the sub panels was by using

```
JPanel subPanel1 = new JPanel();
subPanel1.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(135, 135));
subPanel1.setBackground (Color.white);

JPanel primary = new JPanel();
primary.setBackground (Color.lightGray);
primary.add (subPanel1);
```

I'm unsure of ways to link two images too, and when the second one gets loaded, I want the first one to be cleared out.

Any help on this would be great, thanks.

**EDIT**

My question is, is how to I link two images to one sub panel and make them interchangable

Comment: Put a `JLabel` in `subPanel1`. Change the `Icon` of the label to swap the images. *"Any help on this would be great, thanks."* Do you have any question?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've edited the question. So if I added `Icon` to the `JLabel` in `subPanel1`, it would work?